# Little disks operad and $Gal (\bar {Q}/Q)$ 

Tags: operads, at.algebraic-topology, nt.number-theory

My question is simple:

> How do the little disks operad and $Gal (\bar {Q}/Q)$ relate?

I realize that a huge amount of heavy-machinery can be brought into an answer to this, but I'm struggling with the basics. All papers I've found just seem to jump into the deep-end or involve musings that are more inspirational than precise; so I'm eager to read what people here say.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A short answer would be: $Gal(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$ acts faithfully on the profinite fundamental groupoïd of the operad of little discs.

If $X$ is an algebraic variety over $\mathbb{Q}$ we have an exact sequence 
$$
  1 \to\pi_1(X\otimes \overline{\mathbb{Q}},p) \to 
  \pi_1(X,p) \to Gal(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q}) \to 1
$$
Here $\pi_1(X\otimes \overline{\mathbb{Q}};p)$ is canonically identified with the profinite completion of the usual topological fundamental group $\pi_1(X(\mathbb{C}),p)$. 
If the basepoint is defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, this split and we have an action 
$$
  Gal(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q}) \to Aut(\widehat{\pi}_1(X(\mathbb{C}),p)). 
$$

The (profinite completion of the) fundamental groupoïds of the $C_2(n)$ inherit the operad structure. The trick is that all of it can be defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ as $C_2(n)$ is homotopy equivalent to the configuration space of points on the affine line $F(\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{Q}},n)(\mathbb{C})$. One has to define rational "tangential base points" and check that the operad structure on the fundamental groupoïds is also defined over $\mathbb{Q}$. The resulting operad is described [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/39945/compatibility-of-braids-as-a-simplicial-set-and-as-a-braided-monoidal-category/39981#39981). One can explicitly compute its automorphism group. This is the Grothendieck-Teichmuller group $\widehat{GT}$.

As everything is defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, $Gal(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$ operates on the whole operad. So we have a morphism 
$$
  Gal(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q}) \to \widehat{GT}
$$ 
It follows from a theorem of Belyi that it is injective.

Comment: So once you have an action of the operad on the Hochschild complex (as in Deligne's conjecture) you have many, each conjugated by an element of $\mathrm{Gal}$. Is there an explicit way of seeing the difference between two of this conjugated actions on the complex?

Comment: The Galois action only exists on the profinite completion of the fundamental group. So I don't see how Gal would act in your situation. I don't think the absolute Galois group really appears in the context of Deligne's conjecture. 

Comment: Instead, what appears naturally is the motivic Galois group of mixed Tate motives over $\mathbb{Z}$ (in part because the $F(\mathbb{A}^1,n)$ are mixed Tate over $\mathbb{Z}$). It plays the same role as Gal but for the motivic prounipotent version of the fundamental groups. The two are related by a Zarsiki dense morphism $G_{\mathbb{Q}} \to G^{mot}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Q}_\ell)$ corresponding to the $\ell$-adic realization.    

See Kontsevich's "Operads and motives in deformation quantization".

Comment: PS: I think that writing an explicit action of the operad on the Hochschild complex of $k$-vector spaces usually requires the choice of an associator over $k$. In this case the $k$-points of the motivic Galois group $G_{\mathbb{Z}}(k)$ will act through the prounipotent $GT(k)$ on the coefficients of the associator. If $\mathbb{Q}_\ell \subset k$ you will get an action of $G_{\mathbb{Q}}$ through the $\ell$-adic realization morphism. But the coefficient of this action are very complicated, the simplest are given by the cyclotomic character and Soulé's characters.    

Comment: Do you have a reference for this point of view on the Galois action on the little disk operad, ie the identification of the fundamental groupoids of the little disks with the one obtained from $F(\mathbb A^1,n)$ and certain tangental basepoints? It sounds like you're sketching a realization of the proposal of an algebro-geometric interpretation of the little disks described in Jack Morava's "The motivic Thom isomorphism". In any case this is certainly a "noncanonical" description of the Galois action; the fact that the Galois group sits in $\widehat{GT}$ is explained already in Drinfel'd...

Comment: (cont) in a completely different way, and the fact that $\widehat{GT}$ acts on the operad of little disks is implicit in Bar-Natan's "On associators and the Grothendieck-Teichmüller group".

Comment: I don't have any reference except for my master's dissertation. My main objective was to understand Drinfeld's article not to be original. Bar-Natan's article was very inspiring, the only thing I thought could be improved was that he worked with a free braided monoidal category on one generator while things seemed much more natural when you work with the corresponding operad just like it is simpler to work with fundamental groupoid the moduli space $M_{0,n} = F(\mathbb{A}^1,n)/(\mathbb G_a \rtimes \mathbb G_m)$ than with fundamental group of the quotient $M_{0,[n]} = M_{0,n}/S_n$.

Comment: The main point is that the operad structure doesn't exists on the level of the algebraic varieties but only on the homotopy level. To make the whole thing motivic, you have to compactify the spaces, take point of the tangent spaces with coordinates $\pm 1$ as tangential bases points so you have good reduction over $\mathbb Z$ and check that the Verdier specialization to the normal bundles of the boundary components minus zero section (which are trivial $\mathbb{G}_m$-bundles over lower dimension spaces) induce the right morphisms.

Comment: This line of reasoning allows you to define unconditially the genus 0 Grothendieck Teichmuller tower of fundamental groupoids in the category of mixed Tate motives over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @AFK This is a really great answer! AFK, you mentioned a good source for this is your master's dissertation. Is there a chance it is available online?

Comment: @AFK I am thinking about the issue of an algebro-geometric realisation of the little disks operad in my PhD research. Can you please provide a link to your master's dissertation?