# Galois action on $E_n$-operads

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, at.algebraic-topology, galois-representations, operads

Let $E_n$ be the little $n$-cubes operad which acts on $n$-fold loop spaces (up to group completion, an $E_n$-action is precisely the data needed to perform an $n$-fold delooping). I am looking for precise statements along these lines:

- The $E_n$-operad can be modeled algebraically, over $\mathbb{Q}$ (even $\mathbb{Z}$?). These "spaces" are supposed to come from moduli stacks of curves via some sort of (Deligne-Mumford if $n = 2$?) compactification.
- Let's take $n = 2$, so the spaces of the $E_2$-operad as the classifying spaces of braid groups (and in particular are not simply connected). Then applying the étale homotopy type gives an operad in pro-spaces; the homotopy inverse limit should give an operad in spaces, which at each level is the classifying space of profinite completion of the braid group.
- This gives the profinite completion of the $E_2$-operad an action of $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$. This action is faithful.
- Somehow, this is related to [Drinfeld's associators](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Drinfeld+associator), which are supposed to be related to deformations of braided monoidal (i.e., $E_2$) categories.

I have heard vaguely (from skimming various papers and YBL's answers [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/40287/little-disks-operad-and-gal-bar-q-q) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/39945/compatibility-of-braids-as-a-simplicial-set-and-as-a-braided-monoidal-category/39981#39981)) that there is a story resembling the above four assertions, but I do not know what it is. Could anyone explain this relationship (or suggest references)?

Comment: Do you know http://math.univ-lille1.fr/~fresse/OperadHomotopyBook/?

Comment: @archipelago: yes, I've started skimming Fresse's book, but I haven't quite been able to find these assertions.

Comment: I don't have time to write anything long right now, but I want to comment that the usual explanation for the Galois action on the small disks is not the one you are describing but goes via the Grothendieck-Teichmuller group. GT can be defined as the automorphism group of a completion of the operad of fundamental groupoids of the small disks, you get different flavors of GT depending on what kind of completion you choose. Drinfeld-Ihara proved that the profinite GT contains the absolute Galois group. This is the way it's explained in Fresse's book.

Comment: At the risk of shameless self promotion you might find the brief summary in my paper on the little disk operad useful. It's on the arXiv.

Comment: @Dan: wait, I thought the inclusion of the absolute Galois group into the profinite Grothendieck-Teichmuller group exactly came from a version of this story. Are you claiming otherwise?

Comment: @Qiaochu (This replaces an earlier inaccurate version of this comment) The embedding of Gal into $\widehat{GT}$ that is sketched in Drinfeld's original paper doesn't mention the little disks operad - it says that $\widehat{GT}$ is the automorphism group of the tower of fundamental groupoids of $M_{0,n}$ with tangential basepoints. The fact that GT acts also on the fundamental groupoids of the little disks was only seen later, the first reference is Bar-Natan's paper "On associators and the Grothendieck-Teichmuller group I". AFAIK the first two steps in Akhil's outline are not...

Comment: ...written down anywhere in the literature, but they are probably known to experts (ie not me).

Comment: @DanPetersen: thanks for these comments, and for telling me about your paper. I enjoyed reading it! Cheers,